# ggplot2: mean in the function on time

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have data like this

```
DF <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.Date()-1000, len=1000, by="1 day")[sample(1000, 500)],
  price = runif(500)
)
```

How do I plot e.g. mean of price in the function of time, e.g. in months, using ggplot2?

Comment: Thanks very much for providing a data generator! +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert your dates into months using `cut(,"months")`, then apply `mean` to each month using ggplot `stat_summary`.  Here's how to do it in `qplot`, which is a compact convenience wrapper to `ggplot`.

```
qplot(as.Date(cut(date,"months")), 
  price, data=DF, stat="summary", fun.y="mean", xlab="date")
```

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264786975079660800.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264786975079660800.png)

---

Base plot can also do it:

```
plot(aggregate(DF$price, list(as.Date(cut(DF$date, "month"))), mean))
```

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264786673030283100.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264786673030283100.png)